# Using regex to remove all text after the last number in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Sample Text

```
1234 Main St Smallville, KS 92348Small County
```

Should yield:

```
1234 Main St Smallville, KS 92348
```

Sample Code:

```
return re.match(r'([0-9]+)(?!.*[0-9])', address)
```

Returns:

```
None
```

I've tried every possible pattern I can think of (ex. /d instead of [0-9]) and am completely stumped. Regex is definitely not my strong area. Any suggestions?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\D+$', '', address)` (Note:  This returns an empty string if there are no numbers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the last digit in the string and then remove all the characters after it with `re.sub`:

```
import re
address = "1234 Main St Smallville, KS 92348Small County "
address = re.sub(r'(\d)\D+$', r'\1', address)
print(address) # => 1234 Main St Smallville, KS 92348
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/VMYcdt)

The regex matches and captures into Group 1 a digit (with `(\d)`) and then matches one or more characters other than a digit (`\D+`) up to the end of the string (`$`). The replacement pattern is a mere `\1`, a backreference to the digit we captured with Group 1 (to restore it in the resulting string).

Comment: Curious whether lookbehind will more efficient, or less: `re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\D+$', '', address)`

Comment: Given the current input type (short address strings), I do not think that better performance is key, regex readability has more priority. If the strings are 1k+ characters long, the potential match place inside the string starts to matter more. If it is close to the beginning in a long string, my suggestion is best. The lookbehind solution is almost identical to my suggestion, because the string is processed from left to right, each character is tested whether it is a digit or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use greedy `.*` before `\d+` to make sure to match upto last digits:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^(.*\d+).*$', address)[0]
1234 Main St Smallville, KS 92348
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV8bO0/1)